# cbor2 encoding bytes using Python

Tags: python, cbor

I'm decoding bytes using `cbor2` library but I want to reverse the process to encoding
This is my code

```
import cbor2
cbor_data_decoded = cbor2.loads(b'\xd2\x84M\xa2\x01&\x04H\x0e\x1b)\x96VcIV\xa0Y\x01\x18\xa4\x01bNL\x04\x1aa\x97U\x98\x06\x1a`\xaa\x07\x989\x01\x03\xa1\x01\xa4cvere1.0.0cnam\xa4bfnjAchternaamcfntjACHTERNAAMbgnhVoornaamcgnthVOORNAAMcdobd1963av\x81\xaabtgi840539006bvpj1119305005bmpfCVnCoVbmamORG-100032020bdn\x01bsd\x06bdtj2021-02-18bcobGRbisx$Ministry of Health Welfare and Sportbcix/urn:uvci:01:NL:74827831729545bba1c279f592f2488aX@!\xd7\xdcs<\x139\xea\x9b\x1c;\n\x17\x8e\xdc+\xe3\x14t\x97\x9an\xc9\x1bq\xe8\x020\x0f\x8c\xd1\xe7\xda\xc8 \xc2\x91K\x93\xa7\xac\xf6=E\xd7/\xeb\xecQ>}\xc7\x11\x85ET\x0fy\xf3\x13q\xa9\ng')
print(cbor_data_decoded.value[2])
payload = cbor2.loads(cbor_data_decoded.value[2])
# reverse process
en = cbor2.dumps(payload)
print(en)
```

I want to get the first bytes as a result.

Comment: `print(en[0])` ? not sure what you mean by first bytes

Comment: ```b'\xd2\x84M\xa2\x01&\x04H\x0e\x1b)\x96VcIV\xa0Y\x01\x18\xa4\x01bNL\x04\x1aa\x97U\x98\x06\x1a`\xaa\x07\x989\x01\x03\xa1\x01\xa4cvere1.0.0cnam\xa4bfnjAchternaamcfntjACHTERNAAMbgnhVoornaamcgnthVOORNAAMcdobd1963av\x81\xaabtgi840539006bvpj1119305005bmpfCVnCoVbmamORG-100032020bdn\x01bsd\x06bdtj2021-02-18bcobGRbisx$Ministry of Health Welfare and Sportbcix/urn:uvci:01:NL:74827831729545bba1c279f592f2488aX@!\xd7\xdcs<\x139\xea\x9b\x1c;\n\x17\x8e\xdc+\xe3\x14t\x97\x9an\xc9\x1bq\xe8\x020\x0f\x8c\xd1\xe7\xda\xc8 \xc2\x91K\x93\xa7\xac\xf6=E\xd7/\xeb\xecQ>}\xc7\x11\x85ET\x0fy\xf3\x13q\xa9\ng'```

Comment: I want to get this

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to decode the EU Digital Covid Certificate. The embedded data is encoded with CBOR twice:

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(cbor2.loads(cbor_data_decoded.value[2]))
{-260: {1: {'dob': '1963',
            'nam': {'fn': 'Achternaam',
                    'fnt': 'ACHTERNAAM',
                    'gn': 'Voornaam',
                    'gnt': 'VOORNAAM'},
            'v': [{'ci': 'urn:uvci:01:NL:74827831729545bba1c279f592f2488a',
                   'co': 'GR',
                   'dn': 1,
                   'dt': '2021-02-18',
                   'is': 'Ministry of Health Welfare and Sport',
                   'ma': 'ORG-100032020',
                   'mp': 'CVnCoV',
                   'sd': 6,
                   'tg': '840539006',
                   'vp': '1119305005'}],
            'ver': '1.0.0'}},
 1: 'NL',
 4: 1637307800,
 6: 1621755800}
```

If you're interested I've written an addon for marshmallow that includes these certificates as a code example: https://github.com/Sekenre/marshmallow_cbor/blob/main/examples/dcc.py